# How to Design whether a Class Property has Changed?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, design-patterns

I have a class with about 20 properties but I'd simplify it for this question:

```
public class Product
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

I'd like to have a class or property that identifies whether my class is dirty. By this I mean to identify whether any of its values have changed?

There are 3 design approaches I can take:

1)
When setting the property inside the class, I check whether the property IsDirty.

```
public string Name 
{
    get { return this._name; }
    set { if (this._name != value) { this.IsDirty = true; this._name = value; }
}
```

2)
When setting the property from outside the class, I check whether the property IsDirty.

e.g.

```
if (p.Name != newName)
{
 p.IsDirty = true;
 p.Name = newName; 
}
```

This approach forces me to add lots of ifs in the client class. Some properties are even collections or even reference objects so the number of lines would be increased even.

3)
When the object is ready to be saved, then I check whether any properties IsDirty by getting a cloned object and checking the equality.

This would have a poorer performance as I would have to clone or load again the original object then compare the properties one by one.

Which one is the best design? or is there any other design pattern that can help with this?

Comment: Clone check and Dirty set doesn't have the same bahavior if you change the value then reset it to the original value. Clone won't detect the "change". Whether it's an issue or not is up to you.

Answer (score 5):

Another option would be to Implement the [INotifyPropertyChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.propertychanged%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) Interface.

Please note that this will help you make thing more tidy and your API clearer, but as far as internal implementation regarding keeping track after changes, It is still up to you to implement. I think this goes along best with your `Option #1`

Comment: Our objects are Business Entities used to map NHibernate to Database Tables. That's why I'm relunctant to put logics inside the class. I'd prefer leaving the class simple and plain.

Comment: I disagree.  I think you're being too rigid.  The interface is a good way to do it.

Comment: The INotifyPropertyChanged approach is not a bad idea, but it smells a bit of "passing the buck".  The object just raises events saying "I'm changed!" and another object is now responsible for tracking dirtiness.  This means that client code is now responsible not only for instantiating the object, but also wiring it up to this listener.

Comment: @CSJ The object itself can register to the event, and and do something like: `this.isDirty = true;` This way the object will a.Keep track b. maintain a non volatile indication about the state.

Comment: @TheLight, does my previous comment also answers your comment?

Comment: I appreciate your point. But the problem is that NHibernate is setting the properties initially when loading an object from Database therefore it keeps notifying the changes. Unless I should subscribe just after the object has been loaded. I think that could be done.

Comment: If the events are not intended to be consumed outside the class then this approach is overkill.

Comment: Only certain scenarios (2 out of 10) would need to know about this PropertyChanged thing so this solution would add lots of unnecessary calculations. that's the downside.

Comment: @CSJ I don't think we have information about it. And besides that, It does not cost anything. It is easy to implement, it does not affect performance and the codes intention remains clear.

Comment: This mixes the responsibilities. If I use a Decorator around the sets then the logics to check whether each property has changed or not can be separated.

Comment: I'm thinking using the Decorator pattern with INotifyPropertyChanged interface would be the best approach as it wouldn't violate the SRP anymore.

Answer (score 1):

Option 1 is clearly best: it puts the responsibility of tracking dirtiness where it belongs: inside the object.  Option 2 is out because as you mentioned, you are forcing this responsibility onto the clients of your classes.  And option 3 has the additional problem as you mentioned of performance.

Incidentally, you should look into a proxy implementation using [DynamicProxy](http://www.castleproject.org/projects/dynamicproxy/).  This will allow your code to look like this:

```
public class Product
{
   public virtual int Id { get; set; }
   public virtual string Name { get; set; }
}
```

and with the judicious use of interceptors, you can get the behaviour you want.  You can write an interceptor to intercept any "sets" and do some logic inside, such as setting an IsDirty flag.

Answer (score 0):

Another idea would be to make this a [GoF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern) `Observable` and let interested `Observer` parties register their interest in changes.   It's a more event-based approach.

Comment: Using an observer pattern, would be very similar to approach 1 in the sense the logic for checking and notification would be inside each property. Not sure if it's the best design as it violates SRP.

Answer (score 0):

This is the best solution and complies with SRP principle very nicely, I created the below classes:

- ProductWithChangeDetection; this uses the Decorator pattern to add this new feature to an existing product object
- ProductChangeDetector; this contains logics for  checking and notification. Currently only exposes ChangeDetected property but if more complexity needed one should implement INotifyPropertyChange interface.
- ProductEquitable; this implements IEquitable and has some overloads for checking whether two objects/properties are equal